# why typeof or number check validation is returning false

Tags: javascript

Why number validation is not working in following case.

I'd tried with checking type of value

```
if(typeof value!=='number'){}
```

I'd tried with checking if value is less than 1. The value of variable is 0 by default

```
if(parseInt(value)<1){}
```

Following snippet is working fine, now I want to add additional requirement, check if user has entered number or not and stop further process alerting number if text has been detected.

It is checking null value, working fine with null value, but what is the wrong with `typeof` and `less than 1`.

I'd added the block of code as comment which is not working.

First validation from the comment block is it return false, even we enter number in field.

Second validation from the comment block is partially working, but it has to alert message and break the process, but it is giving `NaN` result.

```js
window.onload=function(){
  bk_issue();
}

function bk_issue(){
    document.getElementById('btn_iss').onclick=function(){
        if(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="book"]:checked').length===0){
            alert('Please check at least one book');
            return false;
        }
        if(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="std"]:checked').length===0){
            alert('Please check at least one student or staff');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            var ttl_qnt = document.querySelector('input[name="book"]:checked').getAttribute('data-id');
            var std = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="std"]:checked');
            var iss_qnt=0;
            for (var i=0;i<std.length;i++){
                var value = std[i].closest('tr').getElementsByTagName('td')[2].querySelector('.qnt').value;
                if(value===''){
                    var std_qnt = 0;
                    alert('Please fill book quantity in checked student field');
                    return false;
                }
            // This validation is not working                
             /* if(typeof value!=='number'){
                    var std_qnt = 0;
                    alert('Please type number only');
                    return false;
                }
                if(parseInt(value)<1){
                    var std_qnt = 0;
                    alert('Please type number only');
                    return false;
                }*/
                else{
                    var std_qnt = std[i].closest('tr').getElementsByTagName('td')[2].querySelector('.qnt').value;
                }
                iss_qnt += parseInt(std_qnt);
            }
                alert(iss_qnt);
        }

    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th><th>Book</th><th>Qnt</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='book' value='1' data-id='20' /></td><td>Social Experiment</td><td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='book' value='1' data-id='12' /></td><td>Evolution of group</td><td>20</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <button id='btn_iss'>Issue</button>
    <br/>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th><th>Name</th><th>Issued Qnt</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' value='1' name='std' /></td><td>Rahul</td><td><input type='text' value='' class='qnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' value='2' name='std' /></td><td>Preeti</td><td><input type='text' value='' class='qnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' value='3' name='std' /></td><td>Prince</td><td><input type='text' value='' class='qnt'></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: an inputs value is **always** a string

Comment: @JaromandaX, so I've added validation, but why it is ignoring.

Comment: i use the `constructor` property these days.   Im not sure if it is better or not though.  I use it to get a bit more goofy instead of comparing string values with typeof, i usually say `value.constructor == (1).constructor`

Comment: @Hemant - your validation doesn't work because the first thing you check, *is it an empty string, if so, that's invalid* (so far so good), the very next thing (commented as not working) you check, *is it a Number, if not, that's invalid* ... and as I said in my comment, an inputs value is **always** a string, therefore, your code considers any input at all to be invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by **@Jaromanda X** an inputs value is always a string so you need to convert it to an integer with `parseInt` and use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if `parseInt(value)` is not a number:

```
if(isNaN(parseInt(value))){
   var std_qnt = 0;
   alert('Please type number only');
   return false;
}
```

```js
window.onload=function(){
  bk_issue();
}

function bk_issue(){
    document.getElementById('btn_iss').onclick=function(){
        if(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="book"]:checked').length===0){
            alert('Please check at least one book');
            return false;
        }
        if(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="std"]:checked').length===0){
            alert('Please check at least one student or staff');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            var ttl_qnt = document.querySelector('input[name="book"]:checked').getAttribute('data-id');
            var std = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="std"]:checked');
            var iss_qnt=0;
            for (var i=0;i<std.length;i++){
                var value = std[i].closest('tr').getElementsByTagName('td')[2].querySelector('.qnt').value;
                if(value===''){
                    var std_qnt = 0;
                    alert('Please fill book quantity in checked student field');
                    return false;
                }
          
                if(isNaN(parseInt(value))){
                    var std_qnt = 0;
                    alert('Please type number only');
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    var std_qnt = std[i].closest('tr').getElementsByTagName('td')[2].querySelector('.qnt').value;
                }
                iss_qnt += parseInt(std_qnt);
            }
                alert(iss_qnt);
        }

    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th><th>Book</th><th>Qnt</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='book' value='1' data-id='20' /></td><td>Social Experiment</td><td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='book' value='1' data-id='12' /></td><td>Evolution of group</td><td>20</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <button id='btn_iss'>Issue</button>
    <br/>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th><th>Name</th><th>Issued Qnt</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' value='1' name='std' /></td><td>Rahul</td><td><input type='text' value='' class='qnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' value='2' name='std' /></td><td>Preeti</td><td><input type='text' value='' class='qnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' value='3' name='std' /></td><td>Prince</td><td><input type='text' value='' class='qnt'></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`value` will always be a string, the best way to check if the string is convertible to a number is `window.isNaN` function (**NOT** to be confused with `Number.isNaN`):

```js
if(window.isNaN(value)) {
  /* act accordingly, the value is not a number */
}
```

If you wish to convert that `value` string into a number just use the `Number` constructor

```js
value = Number(value)
```